# Greater-than clause with CASE in WHERE clause slows query very significantly

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.1000.169)

I have a very long stored procedure that normally runs in about 20 seconds.
Recently, my colleague added the following line to the WHERE clause, and now it takes over 30 minutes to execute.  I can remove this line and it speeds up again, but I can't understand *why* this particular syntax causes SQL Server such a headache:

```
 AND tenants.TenantId >= 
     (CASE WHEN lower(@DBNAME) LIKE '%foo%' THEN 40 ELSE -999 END)
```

This line is meant to exclude the first 39 entries in the `dbo.tenants` table when executed in a certain database.

I know it's horrible, and I'm going to remove it - but I'd like to use the opportunity to better understand why the engine would slow down by orders of magnitude. The tenants table has just over 1000 rows.

If I change the clause to:

```
AND tenants.TenantId != 
    (CASE WHEN lower(@DBNAME) LIKE '%foo%' THEN 40 ELSE -999 END)
```

it is fast again. Furthermore if I change it to something like:

```
AND tenants.TenantId >= 
     (CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 40 ELSE -999 END)
```

it is also fast

**EDIT**
It seems that even if I extract the WHEN condition out to a @variable the performance is bad.
For example:

```
DECLARE @IS_FOO int;
SET @IS_FOO = -999;

...
AND tenants.TenantId >= @IS_FOO
```

It only improves if I replace it with a hard-coded comparison (e.g. WHEN 1=1).

Could there be some kind of DB corruption at play here?

**EDIT 2**
I regenerated the DB from scripts, populated it and rand the query again.  It works fine.  I'm sure all the advice I received here was good - but in this case it seems that the DB was corrupt somehow.  Thanks

Comment: What @HoneyBadger says - solve this by assigning the value to a variable before executing the query

Comment: Also, before the change the stored procedure took 20 seconds (very slow), so I doubt the fact that the Tenants table only has 1000 rows is the root of the issue - this sort of dramatic slowdown is seen where there are already other performance issues - solve those and the effect would likely have not been that noticable

Comment: String manipulations in a where clause are always a bit wonky, for reasons others have pointed out. In this case, you're taking a variable, making it lower and checking to see if it's like a certain pattern. Over and over and over again. I'd do it once, at the beginning and set a flag. Then use that flag in the where clause. There's no reason to keep doing that same calculation on every row, the result is going to be the same every time.

Comment: The cardinality estimates for a `<>` vs. a `>=` comparison are very different if the engine doesn't know the actual range (which it will not know if you're using an expression involving variables). This in turn can trickle through the rest of the query, affecting the execution plan drastically (there's a huge difference between estimating the query will yield 1000 rows or 1 if it's part of a `JOIN`). Even with the condition factored out in a flag, you might need an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get the optimizer to simplify the cases.

Comment: Your table/index statistics were likely out of date.  Changing the operation prevented it from using an existing index so it may have performed a table scan instead.  Based on the behavior you described this may have also caused it to assume a small number of rows were in play so it created a plan with a loop operator, which can be incredibly slow across a large volume of rows.  By regenerating the table, you updated the statistics.